# Nested form: shouldn't save if no information for child is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, nested-forms

I have a nested form to sign up a new organization and 1 member (1:many relationship between organization and its members). Both have validations in the model file and the migration file.

**The issue**: I would like the form not to sign up anything (not organization nor member) if not information for both are entered correctly.

Currently, when I sign up a new organization but leave all the variables for the member empty it signs up the organization without an error message and it signs up no member.

Instead I would want it to try to write the member as well, and then produce an error message because certain variables for the member are not allowed to be empty. Because of that error it should not save the organization either untill also the member information is correct.

This does work correctly if I enter some information for member: if the member then is invalid it doesn't save organization nor member and gives the errors. It also works correctly if I enter valid info for member and no info for organization: it produces error and saves nothing. But it does not work if I enter valid info for organization and no info for member: it produces no errors and saves only the organization.

How should I change my code to adjust this?

---

The view:

```
<%= render partial: "registrationform", locals: { url: organizations_path } %>
```

The partial/form:

```
  <%= form_for @organization, url: url do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <h4>Details of the organization:</h4>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :members do |p| %>
      <h4>Your personal details:</h4>
      <%= p.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= p.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= p.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= p.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "formbutton btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
```

And the controller:

```
  def new
    if (logged_in?)
      flash[:danger] = "You're already logged in"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
    @organization = Organization.new
    @member = @organization.members.build
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(new_params)
    if @organization.save
      @organization.members.each do |single_member|
        single_member.send_activation_email
      end
      flash[:success] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else                            
      @organization.members.build if @organization.members.blank?
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private
def new_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:name,
                 members_attributes: [:email,
                                      :username,
                                      :password,
                                      :password_confirmation
                                      ])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your organization model, you can check for member

```
class Organization
   validate :check_member
   def check_member
      if members.empty?
         errors.add(:base, 'Member is not present')
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: With def check_member I got the error message: `undefined local variable or method 'member' for #<Organization:0x007fadaec07868>`. I also tried `@member.empty?` and `organization.members.empty?` but all generated a similar error message. Each time the error message pointed to `def check_member`.

Comment: I also tried `validates :member, presence: true`. But again the error message `undefined method 'member' for #<Organization:0x007fadaeca1fd0>`, only this time referring to the line `if @organization.save` in `def create` in the controller.

Comment: Answered before accepted, use rails magic:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: For completeness, I also tried `validates_associated :members` as well as `validates_associated :members, presence: true` instead of `def check_member`. But in both cases the form just saved the organization without a member. Restarting the development server made no difference.