# Fails to seed: db with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

Two models, Organization and Member, have a 1:many relationship. On basis of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190890/nested-form-shouldnt-save-if-no-information-for-child-is-entered), I added to my Organization model file:

```
validate  :check_member
  private
  def check_member
    if members.empty?
      errors.add(:base, 'User is not present')
    end
  end
```

As a result it only creates a new organization if also a member for that organization is created. I adjusted my seeds file accordingly since I would now be unable to create an organization without a member:

```
Organization.create!(   name: "Fictious business",
                        address: Faker::Address.street_address,
                        city: Faker::Address.city,
                        website: Faker::Internet.url,
                        subscription: true,
                        subs_exp_date: Faker::Date.forward(365),
                        actioncode: 111,
   members_attributes: [email: "help@example.com",
                        username: "helpzzzz", 
                        password: "foobar", 
                        password_confirmation: "foobar"])
```

However it fails to seed the above, giving the error message: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User is not present" (referring to the error message defined in `def check_member`).

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** It looks like it is something else that's creating the problem. In development I have no problem with seeding. However, seeding to Heroku is when the problem arises. By changing the seeds file, I have found out that when entering `heroku run rake db:seed` it is not seeding with the current, updated seeds file (while it is doing so, in development). It is using the old seeds file where the second part `members_attributes` was not included yet.

What could be the cause of this? A problem at Heroku's side? I've also tried `heroku pg:reset DATABASE`, `heroku run rake db:migrate` and then `heroku run rake db:seed` but it was still using an old seeds file.

Comment: Regarding Heroku: Did you push your latest changes to Heroku?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had not committed the changes to the seeds file to git and therefore `git push heroku` said "Everything up-to-date". If you add this as the solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the members first, then the organization:

```
member = Member.create!(email: ...)
Organization.create!(name: ..., members: [member])
```

Regarding Heroku: Did you push your latest changes to Heroku?

Comment: @Nick [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129095/3102766) if you want a complete explanation.

Comment: It looks like it might be a Heroku problem? See added update to the original post.